# What steps should I take to secure a microk8s installation in 'production'?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

Is microk8s secure enough to use in 'production'? Are there any steps that I should take to secure microk8s if the server it is running on is accessible to the internet?

I’m considering using microk8s for something-close-to-production use. I understand about the issues surrounding whether a single-node kubernetes cluster could ever be considered ‘production’ quality. I’m not looking for reliability, monitorability or any of the other ‘production’ traits - just security. I want to know if I put a microk8s installation on a server that’s connected to the internet - is there anything inherently insecure about this?

Reasoning behind this: I just want a nice interface for orchestrating docker containers on a single server with external access, I’m familiar with kubernetes already as I run a cluster that’s actually for real production, and microk8s is a nice way of installing a single-node kubernetes cluster.

Reference answer to closely-related topic: [Is microk8s suitable for production environments, or is it just for development?](https://serverfault.com/questions/941857/is-microk8s-suitable-for-production-environments-or-is-it-just-for-development)